# get value from livewires.games.Text object

Tags: python-3.x, livewires

I have a `livewires.games.Text` object called score which I am trying to get the value out of. I have tried converting it to a doing `scores = str(self.scores)` and even a for loop:

```
scores = str(self.score)
for item in scores:
    print(item)
```

All I am getting though is `<livewires.games.Text object at 0x1017aca58>`

I am trying to turn the score into an `int()` so that I can use that to base my leveling up in a game I am working on.

Has anyone ever worked with livewires before is there a way to turn the `<livewires.games.Text object at 0x1017aca58>` into an `int()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was:

```
        score = self.score.value
        if score % 100 == 0:
            self.level += 1
            games.screen.add(self.level_msg)
```